# GetMessage with a timeout

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have an application which second thread calls `GetMessage()` in a loop. At some point the first thread realizes that the user wants to quit the application and notifies the second thread that it should terminate. As the second thread is stuck on `GetMessage()`, the program never quits. Is there a way to wait for messages with a timeout?
I’m open to other ideas too.

**EDIT:** (additional explanations)

The second thread runs that snippet of code:

```
while ( !m_quit && GetMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 ) )
{
    TranslateMessage( &msg );
    DispatchMessage( &msg );
}
```

The first thread sets `m_quit` to true.

Comment: Wait... which thread is in the loop waiting on `GetMessage()`?  The first thread, the second thread, or both?

Comment: The second thread runs the ˇGetMessageˇ loop. Should I post some code?

Comment: Code always helps.  I'm just confused because your question makes it seem like both threads are blocked.  Can't you just send a custom message saying "you need to shut down now?"

Comment: The question is interestiong, but I don't see why you need it. Once the main thread is willing to quit, it just have to notify all the thread to finish (`PostQuitMessage` is your friend here), and then wait for them to be finished (`WaitForSingleObject`,  `WaitForMultipleObjects`) and then finish itself.

Comment: @rodrigo mostly because I’m not savvy when it comes to the Windows API :) if this is the recommended way to do things, I will change to that.

Comment: @qdii - Yes, it is. As many people pointed out in the replies below, you should never need the `m_quit` variable in the first place. `PostQuitMessage` does this job with less hassle.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The easiest way is to just call `UINT_PTR timerId=SetTimer(NULL, NULL, 1000, NULL)` before calling `GetMessage`. It will post a `WM_TIMER` message to the calling thread every second, so the `GetMessage` will return promptly. Then, call `KillTimer(NULL, timerId)` to cancel it.

**UPDATE** Sample code:

```
BOOL GetMessageWithTimeout(MSG *msg, UINT to)
{
    BOOL res;
    UINT_PTR timerId = SetTimer(NULL, NULL, to, NULL);
    res = GetMessage(msg);
    KillTimer(NULL, timerId);
    if (!res)
        return FALSE;
    if (msg->message == WM_TIMER && msg->hwnd == NULL && msg->wParam == timerId)
        return FALSE; //TIMEOUT! You could call SetLastError() or something...
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: @rodrigo: +1 . so far the best solution I have seen. I will wait for other candidates to show up.

Comment: @rodrigo watch out for `msg` is a pointer. also, the pointed structure doesn’t have a `uMsg` member, it is called `message`.

Answer (score 25):

Not tested, but you could try the function [MsgWaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) without actually any object.

```
MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(0, NULL, FALSE, timeout, QS_ALLINPUT);
```

If if returns `WAIT_TIMEOUT` it is a timeout, but if it returns `WAIT_OBJECT_0` you can call  `GetMessage` with guarantee not to be blocked.

But note the following:

> MsgWaitForMultipleObjects does not return if there is unread input of the specified type in the message queue after the thread has called a function to check the queue.

So you have to ensure that the last time you called any of the message functions there is no messages left on the queue, or you will have a kind of race condition.

Probably your best option would be to replace `GetMessage` with:

```
if (MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(0, NULL, FALSE, timeout, QS_ALLINPUT) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
{
    while (PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        //dispatch the message
    }
}
```

But as I said before, I didn't test it so I cannot be sure if it will work.

Comment: I just had a deadlock waiting for a **SendMessage** msg with this routine. You should use **QS_ALLINPUT** instead of **QS_ALLEVENTS**, because it also covers **QS_SENDMESSAGE**. see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more info

Comment: Thanks @5andr0 the `QS_ALLINPUT` was what fixed it for me!

Comment: Also, danger for you if you set bWaitAll to TRUE, as I discovered.  Also covered here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/larryosterman/2004/06/02/things-you-shouldnt-do-part-4-msgwaitformultipleobjects-is-a-very-tricky-api/

Answer (score 4):

One thing you can always do is just send the blocked thread a user-defined message that will cause it to wake up, process the message, then go back up to the top of the loop.  In fact, it might be easiest to completely remove the `m_quit` variable and instead to just send the main thread a message that says "you need to quit now."

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1, This helps. I prefer rodrigo’s solution as it keeps the whole quitting mechanism in one place.

Comment: This is a much cleaner method. The point of the thread is to receive messages that tell it what to do. And this doesn't require the thread to wake constantly when there's nothing to do.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to post a quit message to the second thread with `PostThreadMessage`.

E.g.

```
PostThreadMessage(threadid, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
```

You shouldn't need to read the `m_quit` variable in the second thread but you should check for errors from `GetMessage` as well as a return value of `FALSE/0` which is what is returned if the next message is a quit message.

Answer (score -1):

Yep. Try `PeekMessage()` instead. But I think this will not be full problem solving.

Comment: @Forgoth Calling `PeekMessage()` would be a great solution if I could couple it with a `Sleep(1000)`, but in my case the second thread should be very reactive. +1 because the solution is valid in other contexts