# How to kill a wait queue in kernel module?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am new to kernel module. Using a wait queue, I am blocking the thread until the buffer has data. Using `hrtimer`, I am periodically waking up the queue. Now, the problem is even after I remove the kernel module, I could see that the process `"thread1"` is still running. I think the issue is that the wait queue is waiting forever and the process got blocked here. Please help me how can I kill the wait queue when I remove my module.

```c
void thread1(void)
{
    while (thread_running) {
        ...
        wait_event_interruptible(wait_queue, does_buffer_have_data());
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question remembers me of a [WinAPI problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866311/getmessage-with-a-timeout). Before finishing your kernel module, you should set `thread_running` to false and _join_ **thread1** to wait for your timer to wake the queue up and the thread is able to end.

Comment: By "thread", I'm not sure if you are referring to some user process or thread that is using your kernel module, or whether you are referring to a kernel thread that your module has created.

Comment: @Ian Abbott : I am referring to the kernel thread that my module has created.

Comment: one more doubt : If I am using the same wait queue in two different threads and calling `wait_event_interruptible` from any one thread, will it block the other thread also?

Comment: @Karthik - No, it only blocks the thread (or "task" in kernel terminology) that called it. If there are multiple tasks waiting on the same queue, `wake_up_interruptible` call only wakes up one of them, and `wake_up_interruptible_all` wakes up all of them.

Answer (score 7):

Common way for wait within **kernel** thread:

```
void thread1(void)
{
    while(!kthread_should_stop())
    {
        ...
        wait_event_interruptible(wait_queue,
             does_buffer_have_data() || kthread_should_stop());
        if(kthread_should_stop()) break;
        ...
    }
}

void module_cleanup(void)
{
    kthread_stop(t);
}
```

Function `kthread_should_stop` checks `stop` flag for current thread.

Function `kthread_stop(t)` sets `stop` flag for thread `t`, interrupt any waiting performed by this thread, and waits while the thread is finished.

---

Note, that while `kthread_stop` interrupts waiting, it **doesn't set any pending signal** for the thread.

Because of that interruptible *wait for event* (`wait_event_interruptible` and so) doesn't return `-EINTR` just after `kthread_stop` but only rechecks condition.

So, if *waiting for event* wants to be returned after `kthread_stop`, it should **check `stop` flag explicitely in condition**.